# Probability Method Of Recursive number patterns in everyday things

Tags: probability, recursion

I'd like to know how to go about calculating the probability of a recursive number pattern happening in everyday things for an essay which I'm writing.

The example of a recursive number pattern would be this:

In a car park there are 24 (6x4) cars; of which 6 are white, 6 are black, 6 are red and 6 are blue. Again, of these 24 cars, 12 (6x2) are Mercedes, 6 are Hondas and 6 are Fords. And once again, of these 24 cars, 6 are convertibles and 18 (6x3) are not.

How would one go about at calculating the probability of this being completely random?

Comment: What do you mean by "this being completely random"?

Comment: By "this being completely random", do you mean the car brands, car colors and car types are "independent" or "randomly distributed so not independent" or something else?

Comment: Sorry, by "random" I mean coincidence